# Stripe - catch errors and proceed with other payments

Tags: laravel, cron, stripe-payments

I have a cronjob that uses Stripe payments gateway and checks every minute if there are payments pending so it proceeds with them. The problem is when I proceed to fetch each payment and one card for example is declined, the loop is terminated. I need to proceed with other payments and in the end collect the payments declined.

Any idea how can I proceed?!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer your question, but you don't need a cronjob for Stripe payments. The charge request will either immediately succeed or throw an exception. Your code will therefore immediately know whether or not the charge went through.

I may not be fully understanding the situation, so let me know if I'm off base.

Best,
Larry

PS I work at Stripe.

Comment: I am using cronjob in order to execute payments at certain time and based on certain conditions. Normally I have multiple payments to process so the problem is that when an exception occured in one card, an exception is thrown and all other payments do not proceed. My question was how I can execute each payment independent of the other so when one fails, the remain don't get affected.